# Getting access token from Azure using MSAL.PS

Tags: azure, daemon, azure-ad-msal

I have a Powershell script which should be run automatically (daemon) which needs authenticate to Azure AD.
I have a "working" script to  which is getting the correct access token, but this requires me to manually enter username/password. How can I execute the script by having the username/password configured

What has been done:

- A user is created in Azure and Office license has been assigned (this
  is the user which I have to enter username/password for)
- An app registration has been done ($clientid and $clientsecret in
  code below)
- Using MSAL.PS v4.10.0.2

```
$redirecturi = "<redirect url>"
$redirecturi
$scope = '<scope>'

$sec = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientsecret -AsPlainText -Force
$app = New-MsalClientApplication -ClientId $clientid -ClientSecret $sec -RedirectUri $redirecturi -TenantId $tenantid
$az_access_token = $app | get-msaltoken -Scope $scope -LoginHint $loginhint | select -expand accesstoken
```

Comment: Please create 2 variables to store the client id & client secret. While running the script, read the secrets from a Json or any config file and then pass those values as parameters. Note: you need to store the secrets first in Json file in a secured location. If you are not familiar with Json, use any kind of config file.

Comment: Hi,  the problem is not how to provide the client id/client secret.  The problem is how to provide the user credentials to the user indicated in the -LogonHint argument.  If I provide a value pointing to a valid user in Azure AD, I get a logon dialog asking for the password.  If I leave out the -LogonHint argument, I get an access token, but this is only for the app registration and not for the user.  I want to be able to provide the username and password of the user in -LogonHint in the script as this will be running  as a daemon process

Comment: As per the client credentials flow, there will not be any users associated. So, you need to set up application permissions in the Azure portal. You need to modify the manifest file of the API application to add roles in it. That role you can pass in the scope array of your python script. Please let me know if you want to know how to set up application permissions.

Comment: For example, user.read is a delegated permission where as user.read.all is an application permission. To set up application permission, you may need consent from the Azure ad admin of your tenant.

Answer (score 0):

[Application credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) are the best suited for daemon applications like yours. If you still need to authenticate as a user then you can opt for [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) which is not recommended.

I'm afraid you will have to input credentials manually using MSAL.PS so they can be cached and silently used later thus not much of automation here unless you replace or use custom tools.

Comment: Great answer! Even if the ROPC flow is not recommended, it is the route I'm taking in this situation.  Thank you very much for directing me in the right direction :-)

Comment: @KjetilBustnes Anytime :)

Comment: @KjetilBustnes would you please share the powershell script that prompts for username and password? I have a very similar usecase as yours and i need the script. Thanks!